# Finding the visible height of a textarea

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the visible height of a textarea (i.e. the number of lines that are currently visible to the user).I have the textarea height and width setting using the following CSS:

```
textarea
{
height:90%;
width:90%;
}
```

When I attempt to find the rows attribute it returns the value 2, which is not correct. I have  tried a variety of other ways, such as offsetHeight, etc. but havn't had much luck. Can anybody make any recommendations on how to do this or point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: You want this - http://jsfiddle.net/R6tfZ/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I attempt to find the rows attribute it returns the value 2, which is not correct.

It is correct, the `rows` attribute and `height` property are mutually exclusive.

---

```
var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0]​​​​​​​;

alert(textarea.scrollHeight);​
```

Comment: Not sure what I was doing wrong, but when I initially used scrollHeight I was only ever getting 0 returned. This works great now though.